# ember routes, what does 'this' refer to?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm familiar with how **this** is used in JS.

The example from the ember docs for creating routes is:

```
 Router.map(function() {
 this.route('about', { path: '/about' });
 this.route('favorites', { path: '/favs' });
 });
```

Their explanation leaves a bit to be desired:

*"When calling map(), you should pass a function that will be invoked with the value **this** set to an object which you can use to create routes."*

What object? A global router object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print out `this` or if you debug the code you will see that `this` within `map` method is in fact an instance of [DSL](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.12.0/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/dsl.js) object. It is hidden down in the api; what really occurs is that; [Ember.Router](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.12.0/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/router.js) creates an instance of `DSL` and generates corresponding path matches via this object and passes it down to the actual [router](https://github.com/tildeio/router.js/) encapsulated by `Ember.Router` itself. Of course within our app we only deal with `Ember.Router` and does not know about the details of other classes. If you are interested you can track the source code from the links I have provided (that is what I had done for some work just a week ago).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Like you said it's [`Router`](https://www.emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Router.html) object. that's defined in router.js file top place. but we will not use properties inside `map` function.

We can make use of properties and its methods in [Router](https://www.emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Router.html), like the below I demonstrated didTransition callback which is useful callback after all the transition completed.

```
const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
    location: config.locationType,
    rootURL: config.rootURL,
    myService:Ember.inject.service(),    
    didTransition() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        console.log(' After all the router transition complete ', ...arguments);
        //if you override anywhere didTransition dont forget to return true to allow chain to reach here
        return true;
    }
});
```